# Is it necessary to create multiple streamreader instances to read multiple files?

Tags: c#, performance, file, streamreader

I am wanting to read the text of multiple files into a string using a streamreader, but as of right now, my code has me creating a new streamreader every time I want to read a different file. This works, although when repeated hundreds of times, it seems highly inefficient. I am sure this is a very easy fix, but I am still new to programming, so a bit of knowledge would be much appreciated.

An example of the inefficient code I would like to avoid:

```
someloop
{

    using (StreamReader sR = new StreamReader(changingfilename))
    {
      textString = sR.ReadToEnd();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading from disk is comparatively very slow. The instantiation of a StreamReader is negligible is comparison. The slow part is ReadToEnd(), not new StreamReader(). Try to avoid reading from disk if your code is too slow.

Some versions of Visual Studio ship with a profiler which will tell you exactly which methods are spending cpu/clock time of your program

Comment: So if I am understanding you correctly, it is impossible to avoid the lag time that accompanies reading a file completely?

Comment: Yes. Doing IO(disk, network, db) is much slower than cpu and memory operations.

Comment: Unless you are reading the same file multiple times. You can then store the contents in memory. It is unclear from your question if you read the same file multiple times.

Comment: No, it is a different file every time (so your original answer suits me perfectly). Thank you!

Comment: Since you mention lag time it indicates that you are running this in a ui of some sort. You can avoid blocking the gui while reading by performing the reading in a different thread. Combines with a progress bar the lag will perceived as shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have to create a stramreader for each file what you can do is
create an array and read it like this

```
List<string> lstFileNames=new List<string>();
StringBuilder stringBuffer=new StringBuilder();
lstFileNames.Add("File1");
lstFileNames.Add("File2");
for(int i=0;i<lstFiles.Count;i++)
{
     using (StreamReader sR = new StreamReader(lstFiles[i]))
    {
        stringBuffer.Append(sR.ReadToEnd());
    }
}
```

User string builder for appending strings.

Comment: But will this be faster, considering it now involves creating extra variables?

Comment: It won't. Not because of extra variables, but because the same amount of reading is performed.

Answer (score 0):

A better way would be to simply let .NET handle this for you an use the `File.ReadAllText(yourFileNameAndPath)` static method.